# Why is the format of my inverse function wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function

Why is the correct answer for $h(x)=\dfrac{-2x-1}{x+5}$ given by $h^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{5x+1}{-2-x}$ instead of $h^{-1}=4x-1$? Why do I stop at $\dfrac{5x+1}{-2-x}$?

Comment: How did you get $4x-1$ as the inverse function?

Comment: I think it came from "simplifying" the actual inverse by combining the numerator and denominator additively.

Comment: What?  Because $h^{-1} = 4x - 1$ is wrong, and $h^{-1}(x) = \frac {5x+1 }{-2-x}$ is right???  What possible answer could you want?  What do you mean "why do I stop at"?  How would you keep going?  Going where?

Comment: It will help tremendously if you show your work to arrive at $4x-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions $\frac{5x+1}{-2-x}$ and $4x-1$ are not at all the same. Try plugging some numbers in to both. There's no good way to simplify a rational function like $\frac{5x+1}{-2-x}$, unless you can factor something out of both the numerator and the denominator, and then cancel.

Comment: I just tried to "prove" my work and I see my error. For one I was trying to combine the equations on one side only and doing it wrong! and I want to keep ALL x's on one side of the equation to get y=.  So sorry to waste everyone's time. Thank you for pointing out what I was doing wrong and answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

$$h(x)=y=\frac{-2x-1}{x+5}=\frac9{x+5}-2$$
$$y+2=\frac9{x+5}$$
$$x+5=\frac9{y+2}$$
$$x=\frac9{y+2}-5=\frac{-5y-1}{y+2}=\frac{5y+1}{-2-y}$$
$$\therefore h^{-1}(x)=\frac{5x+1}{-2-x}$$